# iOS App not combining achievement events

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Usually, if you get multiple upvotes on one answer/question, they are collapsed into one "event" with the number indicating the total rep earned. So, if you have 6 upvotes and one downvote, you have +58 instead of 6 +10 and one -2 (though the downvotes don't usually show in the activity feed).

Anyway, here's an image.

[image: achievements list]

As a note, I have restarted the iOS app and hard reset my phone. This does not seem to affect the iPad version of the app (1.3.2), which is still combining the events properly.

iOS app version 1.4.0 running on iPhone 6 iOS 8.1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Achievements are combined with a key based that looks like `{title}-{link}`. Due to a change in 1.4.0, keys went from being `iOS App not combining achievement events-http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266910/` to being `<SEAPIHTMLString:0x1234>-http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266910/` where `0x1234` was different for each item.  This made them impossible to group them.

Comment: @Catija The change hasn't been released yet.  We should be shipping to the app store in the next two weeks.

Comment: Ah! That's so funny! I could have sworn it had been fixed recently but I think it must have been that I haven't gotten many upvotes! ... which is sort of sad but c'est la vie!