# Rep Point changes aren't showing in iOS app achievements tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

So... I know that a couple of months ago I complained about the [reputation points not stacking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266910/ios-app-not-combining-achievement-events)... and that's getting fixed...

But now they're not showing up at all. All I'm seeing under "Achievements" in the iOS app is badges awarded.

[image: iOS view of Achievements]

Now, to compare, here's my achievements pane on FF:

[image: Firefox Achievements]

I did check... I haven't installed a new version of the iOS app... though I do know that some updates can be pushed without a new version.

The same thing is occurring on my iPad and iPhone.

Comment: At least it's showing something, in the android app it's [just showing the spinner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270501/achievements-view-loads-forever-never-showing).

Comment: And if you don't have any recent badges, it tells you you have no reputation.  Me too, in other words.

Comment: JFTR: the message I get has "No Achievements" and "You have not earned any achievements yet".  I think that's slightly inaccurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy of the public API.

Comment: I can confirm that it is working once more for me.  Thank you.