# iOS app Achievements list is missing entries

Tags: bug, ios-app, achievements-dialog

The Achievements view controller is quite empty:

[image: screenshot]

Compared to the web version, which I can continue scrolling pretty far:

[image: web screenshot]

I realize some of these achievement types are new (from the docs beta) and not supported, but that probably shouldn't cause the list to be mostly empty.

This seems similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270523/131139, but that one was supposedly fixed.

Comment: Also (pinging @BrianNickel), it would be nice if the app would post screenshots like this at higher (native) resolution :)

Comment: Ugh.  It looks like the web has access to up to the last 50 achievement clusters (+160 = 1 cluster) derived from the last 250 rep events and the API only has access to the last 50 district events (+160 = 32 events).  Your screen is showing 40 events after dropping 10 docs events.

Comment: Would that also cause [this problem](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/965/docs-has-busted-the-app), then, by chance?

Comment: Tangentially related. Every time they roll out a new badge, the feed and achievements break until Mobile and API are built out.

Comment: Actually... it looks like the docs rep items are now coming through.